# Does the principle of explosion contain all analytic knowledge?

Tags: logic, metaphysics, semantics

“From falsehood or contradiction anything follows”.

Is this the “multiverse” or pluralism in which set theory, all logics, etc are a small portion?

Every finite list of axioms and theorems would have to exist. Even if they lead to contradiction. But are some metaphysics or systems “large” enough to contain them?

If you don’t like it as a metaphysics, maybe as a semantics?

And if you don’t like it as a metaphysics, what about under a system or metaphysics or logic where truth, falsehood, and contradiction aren’t “prohibited”. Things like a deflationary theory of truth (and falsity?), Paraconsistent logic, Quine’s no true antimonies, etc. Systems which don’t just throw up their arms at a contradiction.

With all its downsides, one way this is appealing is it seems like the greatest possible structure conceivable.

Comment: Cantor seems to have had an intuition to this effect when he muddied his definition of absolute infinity by speaking of "inconsistent multiplicities." Model-theoretically, suppose we have a cardinal that encodes for a true explosion. This makes it strong enough to prove everything, so an explosion cardinal would have to outrank virtually any other cardinal (in such a system). Nevermind that it outranks itself, as well!

Comment: @KristianBerry thanks. By encoding for a true explosion does that just mean writing a contradiction with some number?  Thanks for the tip about Cantor maybe I can find more info that isn’t woo

Comment: "Does the principle of explosion contain all analytic knowledge?" I do not think so... Logics that reject Explosion will not necessarily think that logic is empirical.

Comment: I'm not well-versed enough in how model theory is used to compare the sizes of cardinals to say for sure, but the template is something like, "If the set [whose cardinality is in play] yields a [transitive] model of a theory of other (lower) sets, then it can prove the lower theory relatively consistent, and since the sets in the lower theory are not able to prove the consistency of their own encoding theory, the set that can prove this must be larger than they are."

Comment: Granted, an explosion cardinal would not be cashed out in terms of relative consistency proof strength, although if an explosion occurred, it would license the inference to both, "The law of noncontradiction is never true," as well as "is always true," so maybe the explosion would then implode.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But every axiom, theorem, proof in those Logics exist in the exploded mulitiverse

Comment: A logic in which everything is true is just uninteresting. It's nearly meaningless, because meaning of a proposition derives from what follows from that proposition and what does not follow. It's like a picture in which every pixel is 100% white.

Comment: @causative Except we can still pick out structure. It's more like the blank canvas and you have a pen.

Comment: @JKusin Not much structure, considering that the shortest proof for any proposition would just be the principle of explosion. No, you don't have a pen; the content of the canvas is determined by the axioms, i.e. each "pixel" represents whether a particular proposition can be proved, and they all can, so the canvas is permanently, axiomatically white.

Comment: @causative You're right, if that's all we wanted was the shortest proof. But this "canvas" has "anything". Every "proof" would real, not just the shortest. If you wanted the shortest proof, your example exists. If someone else wanted some set of premises and conclusions  that fit their notion of sets and first order logic, they'd choose that portion.

Comment: @JKusin Well, what interesting questions would you ask about such a system, that you couldn't ask about a consistent logic? You don't need an inconsistent logic to model sets and first order logic - really, self-contradiction is detrimental to such modeling. To model sets and first order logic you would have to first throw out any inconsistencies you find.

Comment: @causative I guess one wonder I have is how math feels both discovered and invented. This is kind of both. And if I can define something, that is all that matters to count as math or logic. Intuitionism, constructivism, logicism, unrestricted comprehension or not, forcing or not, categories, sets, paraconsistent. Treat them all as real as long as one can define it through language. Every foundation seems too limiting when we have so many ways to define things.

Comment: "Every finite list of axioms and theorems would have to exist. " I'm concerned about this statement. *Inconsistent axiom systems don't have models.* That is, they don't "exist." It's not true that every axiom system brings a model into existence. Only the consistent systems do. That's Gödel's completeness theorem . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem

Comment: @user4894 thanks for this. I will have to read this very carefully.

Comment: @user4894 it seems only consistent first order logics have a model by completeness. This pluralism would preserve first order logic’s models and the completeness  theorem there. Now maybe this has other problems but this one seems surmountable?

Comment: Certainly PoE could contain everything including analytic knowledges if you metaphorically identify it with the big bang lol, something similar to Cantor's (in)famous "absolute infinity" intuition/speculation...

Comment: this is the type of structure I am still trying to understand better (didn’t have at the time) http://math.andrej.com/2012/10/03/am-i-a-constructive-mathematician/ “I put forward the thesis that each mathematical world has its own idea of what all the worlds have in common. Of course, this leads to the (quite realistic) possibility that the various mathematical worlds disagree about what the various mathematical worlds are. What counts as mathematics in one world might not in another!” I felt only a few commenters engaged and the rest were dismissive but I probably needed to phrase it better.

Answer (score -1):

> Does the principle of explosion contain all analytic knowledge?

No.

The principle of explosion isn't even a logical principle. Essentially, it is the fallacious consequence of interpreting the material implication as an implication. Fallacious because "*A materially implies B*" is just "*Not A or B*", and the expression "*Not A or B*" does not imply that A implies B.

Human beings have a very limited logical capacity. This is demonstrated by the history of the development of mathematical logic, which was characterised by extensive analytical discussions involving many mathematicians and philosophers. Most of these analyses were based on false premises. Mathematical logic started out as the mathematical study of human logic, but the initial idea got lost in the process. Today, mathematical logic has zero connection to human logic. It is mathematics, and  as such mathematical logic reasonings are logical, but mathematical logic has nothing to say about human logic, and therefore nothing to say about anything outside mathematical logic.

Analytic knowledge?  What is that? Logical reasoning can only at best tells you what follows logically from your beliefs or from arbitrary premises, and beliefs are not knowledge and what follows from beliefs is not knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

“From falsehood or contradiction anything follows”.

Just means that

(false -> true)  is true

and

(false -> false) is also true.

Or, if you want it more high-level, if your premises are wrong, then the conclusion contains no information.

Comment: Doesn’t it more closely mean [false and true] -> “everything”. Well some people think logic is real (it says something about the world )and there are contradictions. Someone like Graham Priest. He just doesn’t go quite this far I don’t think. He doesn’t think all logics exist just some plurality. So I don’t think I’m completely off base.

Comment: @JKusin "[false and true]" is just "false" and "everything" is not a truth value. What I mean is that "Unicorns_exist -> Santa_Claus_exists" might be true but doesn't tell you anything about the existence of Santa Claus if it turns out "Unicorns exist" isn't true. And that is because "Unicorns_exist -> ~ Santa_Claus_exists" is also true. Of course this answer assumes law of excluded middle.

Comment: [False and true] is not just false in every logic. The LEM is not assumed in every logic either. Many logicians are saying pluralism is catching on. This is an extreme pluralism.

Comment: @JKusin In such logics, does the principle of explosion even hold? The principle of explosion can only hold if (false -> false) is true, right? Because that is exactly what the principle of explosion is saying.

Comment: I’m not sure how these logics meet up. PoE is “true” in classic logic, or at least it’s proven in classical logic that if there’s contradiction, everything follows. In paraconsistent L, PoE is “false” or denied. Contradictions provably not lead to every possibility there. But there’s no neutral logic to say whether one should accept or deny the PoE (that contradictions lead to everything). Priest thinks there are contradictions but not everything follows (para). Others think there are no contradictions. I’m wondering why not accept contradictions and PoE so everyone is “right” and we avoid…

Comment: …having to pick one logic or one subset. The only logical way I know how to get everything is the PoE

Comment: @JKusin In logics where PoE is true, PoE doesn't "contain all knowledge", it contains no knowledge. In a logic where contradictions can be true, there can be no PoE (at least not with contradictions that are true).

Comment: I’m not sure that ability to prove anything is the same as no knowledge. You seem very certain of that.